# Can I insert a variable into TwiML? In particular, to insert the phone number of the number called?

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to implement the following in TwiML? The goal is to produce a reasonably-sounding voicemail on Twilio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Pause length="15"/>
    <Say voice ="woman">
        You have reached the voice mail of ##The_Phone_Number_One_has_Called##.
        Please leave a message at the beep.
    </Say>
    <Record
        transcribe="true"
        />
</Response>
```

I have a bunch of Twilio numbers and would like to have the string `"##The_Phone_Number_One_has_Called##"` replaced by the number that the caller is calling. Please advice if I should deploy a dedicated TwiML for each phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it on your server's code. Just replace the "##The_Phone_Number_One_has_Called##" with the phone that the user called.

Remember that you get the number that the user dialed on the post param "To" on each of Twilio's requests to your server, so from your server you could return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Pause length="15"/>
    <Say voice ="woman">
        You have reached the voice mail of $POST["To"].
        Please leave a message at the beep.
    </Say>
    <Record
        transcribe="true"
        />
</Response>
```

And your server will render a different phone each time, and Twilio's will say it. Just a heads up, the $POST["To"] has the format "+1XXXXXXXXXX", so you might want to remove the +1.

Answer (score 1):

Using Templates with a TwiML Bin, and Polly voices, try something like this for the bin:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Pause length="15"/>
    <Say voice="Polly.Joanna">
        You have reached the voice mail of 
          <say-as interpret-as="telephone">{{To}}</say-as>.
        Please leave a message at the beep.
    </Say>
    <Record
        transcribe="true"
        />
</Response>
```

---

- How to use templates with TwiML Bins
  (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368-How-to-use-templates-with-TwiML-Bins)
- Amazon Polly
  (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#amazon-polly)